# Working out maximum current on connectors

Tags: electrical, wago

If a [Wago 221](https://www.wago.com/global/electrical-interconnections/discover-installation-terminal-blocks-and-connectors/221) is rated at 600 V, 20 A, then if you put it into a 240 V system, what does the maximum current become?

I thought it dropped to 8 A, but trying to remember which way this goes always gives me a headache. I am getting confused with current through transformers.

Comment: Ah, I see what happened there.  If you don't [register your account](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/creating-accounts) with StackExchange (by tying it to an email, google or facebook), and then log in from a different device or browser, it creates a second account on that other device. That's what happened.  Just register from the browser/device you originally asked the question on, or follow [this](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge them.

Comment: @jay613 a quick google search confirms you're right - feel free to just edit for improvements like that, and if its wrong then can be rolled back easily.

Answer (score 24):

The current rating depends on the conductors. The voltage rating depends on the insulation.

Those ratings are independent of each other in connectors, so it's fine to push 20A through the Wago while it's on a 240V circuit.

Comment: Though they also depend on what standard the product is being approved to. It seems that under European standards the connector has a lower voltage rating but a higher current rating than under US standards.

Comment: @PeterGreen that's interesting.   And a rabbit hole for people who are interested in that sort of thing.  Perhaps getting a rating over 450V in Europe would subject the connectors to a different, more expensive certification regime that doesn't help the product's business plan.    From OP's perspective, all that matters is that 240 < 600 and that a 20A breaker will protect this.

Comment: ... and you can _still_ only push 20A through it if you have installed it on a 12V circuit (e.g.  inside a caravan).

Answer (score 13):

The current rating is 20A regardless of the operating voltage.

The connector and conductors have a small amount of resistance, which causes power loss when current flows. This power loss is proportional to the square of the current (*rms* current, more accurately) and is in the form of heat which must be dissipated to the surroundings.  The current rating is based on limiting the resulting temperature rise to a safe level, and is independent of the operating voltage

Answer (score 2):

The ratings are based on safety rules.

The voltage limit (600 V here) is based on the breakup voltage of the insulation. Air **is** insulation here as well.

The current limit (20 A here) is based on the resistance (or conductivity) of the conductor and the wire-to-junction transition resistance and the thermal stability of the insulators.

These are independent phenomena and must be treated independently.

No matter what current flows through the junction if there is voltage drop between two wires higher than the breakup voltage there will be a discharge. Low voltage devices usually don't need extra features but high-voltage switches do have discharge-suppressing systems, so do the high-current but they are off-topic already.

No matter the voltage between terminals the wire itself has some resistance that cause a voltage drop. As you might know, the power cosumed in a resistor (here the wire or junction is a resistor) is proportional to the current squared. The power is "consumed" as a heat. After enough time the junction will reach dynamic equilibrium (the heat production will be equal to heat losses through radiation and conduction), but the higher the power is, the higher temperature will be reached. Overshooting the current limit may cause the insulation to melt or burn, it may cause the junction box lose the shape and fail mechanically.

So, the 20A WAGO junction should be loaded by 20 A on any system. 600V, 240V, 110V, 12V,...

What do drop with the mains voltage is the power rating. Using this junction you can power 12 kW device on 600V system but 4.8 kW on 240V system and 240 W on 12V system.

Also note that keeping yourself within these limits will keep you safe but keeping yourself within with a margin will keep the circuit more stable and efficient. You know, 40A rated wire won't heat that much as 20A rated one...